# Watchkit - How to schedule notification only for Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have created an App with Apple Watch extension.

I would like to know if it's possible to schedule a notification that only appears on the Apple Watch. And conversely, can we schedule a notification to only appear on the  iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question, but unfortunately it is not possible at this time. Apple is trying to be very pragmatic about how they direct notifications. If you iPhone is unlocked, they assume you are looking at it and will route notifications there. If you iPhone is locked, then all notifications will be routed to your Apple Watch. They want to avoid duplicated notifications in both locations at all costs.

Currently there is no ability to force route remote or local notifications directly to the Watch only. If you feel strongly about this feature, then I would suggest you file an enhancement [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with the Apple Bug Reporting System.

Comment: your answer is bothering me. I went to iPhone simulator and locked it and saw the watch simulator there local notification is not triggered  ;(

Comment: You cannot trust the watch simulator behavior here as it does not entirely support the Watch OS. There are many features that the Watch simulator does not yet properly support. This is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

In the official Apple documentation they said that:

> Apple Watch takes full advantage of the existing interactive
>   notification support on iOS. If your iOS app supports notifications,
>   Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times. When
>   one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s
>   iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone
>   or on the Apple Watch. For notifications sent to Apple Watch, the
>   system lets the the user know subtly that a notification is available.
>   If the user chooses to view the notification, the system displays an
>   abbreviated version of the notification first, followed by a more
>   detailed version. The user can dismiss the detailed notification,
>   launch your WatchKit app, or act on the notification by tapping an
>   available action button.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html

So I think you can tell to iOS the behavior of your notifications (**When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s
iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone
or on the Apple Watch. For notifications sent to Apple Watch, the
system lets the the user know subtly that a notification is available.**)

Comment: Ok. But how to send notifications to Apple Watch only?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but, in the traditional APN payload for iPhone apps, you didn't have to specify a "category" (what it is a must in AppleWatch notifications). So I image that if you specify a category in the payload of your push notifications, iOS will show the notification first in your AppleWatch ( See file PushNotificationPayload.apns => {
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "EnriMR sent you a new message",
            "title": "Optional title"
        },
        "category": "newMessage"
    },
    ...
})

Comment: You're talking about Remote Notification but I'm using Local Notification... When I create Local Notification, I can't specify a category.

Comment: @EnriMR dont post some random answer. Give solution to trigger notification in watch. Thanks if you can do that

Comment: @iOSdev this is not a random answer, this is taken from official AppleWatch forum. You can check it if you want. Thanks

Comment: @EnriMR Thanks for your immediately reply basically I want to trigger notification in watch but you say apple doesnt support as of now then what is the perfect way to trigger notification if apple doesnt have an answer? Which is what making me think like that.Justify ur answer

Comment: I'm going to the AppleWatch Lab next week, so I could ask this to Apple developers but for now, my answer and cnoon's answer are everything we can do. Figure out that this is not your question, so if you have another issue different from Souffiane one, you must create a different question